# XSD error - restriction tag and namespace

Tags: xml, xsd

In my .xsd file I have

```
<meters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Meter.xsd">

....

</meters>
```

but the parser says I have a fatal error right at the end of the  line. At the less than sign. The error is:

```
Message: Fatal error encountered during schema scan
```

My next error is

```
<xs:simpleType name="ID.Type">
    <restriction base="xs:String">
        <xs:enumeration value="space2"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="space1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

At the end of the closing restriction tag it says there's an error. The error is

```
Message: Expected end of tag 'restriction'
```

I've closed the restriction opening restriction tag though? The syntax is the same as w3Schools for the restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second error, your open tag is `<restriction>`, while the close tag is `</xs:restriction>`. The two tags are in different namcespace and hence they don't match.

Change the open tag to `<xs:restriction>` should fix it.